# Laravel - Share variable between controller functions

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm new to Laravel and working on a simple project where in my controller **(TestController)** i have two functions **(process & show)**.

What i'm trying to do is pass **$email** variable between the functions, so i can use it within the show function, but i don't know how to do that.

**Controller**

```
class TestController extends Controller
{    

    public function process(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()) {
            $email = $request->get( "fullemail" );
        }
    }


    public function show(){

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

---

**EDIT**

I'm edited my code as followed. Currently i get `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TestController::show(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected` Error.

**Controller**

```
class TestController extends Controller
{    
    public function process(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()) {
            $email = $request->get( "fullemail" );
            $this->show($email);
        }
    }

    public function show($email){
        dd($email)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have reached laravel and know what functions are, you probably already know how to do this:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{    

    public function process(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()) {
            $email = $request->get( "fullemail" );
            $this->show($email);
        }
    }


    public function show($email){
        // Do whatever you will with the $email variable.
        return view('some.view', ['email' => $email]);
    }

}
```

An alternative approach:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{    

    // Declare this variable as a class property - protected means, that only this class and any class that inherits from this class can access the variable.
    protected $email;

    public function process(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()) {
            $this->email = $request->get( "fullemail" );
            $this->show();
        }
    }


    public function show() {
        // Do whatever you will with the $email variable.
        return view('some.view', ['email' => $this->email]);
        // On top of that, if you change $email value here, the changes will be available in all other methods as well.
        // $this->email = strtolower($this->email);
    }

}
```

Comment: I get `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TestController::show(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected` . I've updated my question. Can you take a look?

Comment: Make sure that $email is not null, or make the `show` method's parameter optional like so: `public function show($email = '')`. Alternatively, you can do: `$email = $request->get('fullemail', 'default value');`.

Comment: I assume he calls `show()` from Blade without the mandatory argument.

Comment: @commonsense I added the `return view()` part - OP's code does not contain it.

Comment: I'm sure $email is not null. i can see the value when i dd. if i use `public function show($email = '')` in show function it returns $email as null

Comment: Then I have no idea. Try renaming `show` method to something else, see if there's any conflicts anywhere outside of this controller. All I can suggest, because it does not get more straight forward than just passing a value from one method to another.